# Continuous Pareto Distribution Intuition

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I've searched all *Google* and I did not find any good and clear explanation about this:

Let's suppose that we want use *Pareto Distribution* with **X axis** expressing ranges of some income proxy and **Y axis**, some population proxy.

$$\color{blue}{ PDF(x) = \alpha/ x^{\alpha+1}}$$

Where $\color{blue}{x >=1}$ and $\color{blue}{\alpha>1}$

I know the $\color{blue}{PDF(x)}$ shows for continuous and increasing income bands, something related to the proportion of the population that earn at least the corresponding to that range. So $\color{blue}{PDF(1)}$ is the bigger value because it's the lower income range.

It there somebody that can explain to me without excessive formalism why  does $\color{blue}{CDF(x)}$ generates population size proxy within the given range of $\color{blue}{x}$ values?

$\color{blue}{\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad CDF(x) = 1 - (1/x)^{\alpha}}$

So we have

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \color{blue}{P=1 - CDF(x)}\;$  `(1)`

Where $\color{blue}{P}$ is proportion from population with income greater than $\color{blue}{x}$

If I take for granted that $\color{blue}{CDF(x)}$ sums the population it's not so hard to understand why $\color{blue}{ \int x PDF(x) dx}$ returns a proxy for total income.

From $\color{blue}{1}$ to $\color{blue}{\infty}$ it gives $\color{blue}{\alpha/(\alpha-1)}$. From $\color{blue}{x}$ to $\color{blue}{\infty}$ it gives $\color{blue}{\alpha/(\alpha-1)(x^{1-\alpha})}$

So the rate $\color{blue}{I}$  of superior income on total income is  $\color{blue}{I = x^{1-\alpha}\;}$ `(2)`

If I select values for income and populations proportions in `(1)` and `(2)` and combine them, we have 2 equations with 2 incognitos.( $\color{blue}{x}$ and  $\color{blue}{\alpha}$):

$$\color{blue}{\alpha = 1/(1-\log_{P} I)}$$

For instance, let's suppose that we want to define a *Pareto Distribution* where $\color{blue}{P = 20\%}$ of richer population win $\color{blue}{I = 80\%}$ of total income (one of the classic assumptions), so:

$$\color{blue}{\alpha = 1/(1-\log_{20\%} 80\%) \sim 1.161}$$

The $\color{blue}{x}$ that reaches `80%` of the population is:

$$\color{blue}{x = 80\%/20\% = 4}$$

And it's right, because $\color{blue}{CDF(4) = 80\%}$, i.e.,
$\color{blue}{1 - CDF(4) = 20\%}$ are the richer people.

Using `(1)` the rate of superior income on total income is  $\color{blue}{x^{1-\alpha}=80\%}$

So everything works smoothly but I dont't understand, after all, why $\color{blue}{CDF(x)}$ is related to total population.

Why?

**PS**: In this case, I'm not interested about *Lorenz Curve*. It's related to a explanation about a $\color{blue}{CDF(x)}$ behaviour.

**UPDATE**

The below answer fully clarified my doubt.

In fact, like `@StubbornAtom` has showed, $\color{blue}{CDF(x)}$ is built-in associated to some $\color{blue}{x}$ (income, revenue, profit, counting) proportion in a universe (population, items, products)

Suppose that $\color{blue}{x}$ is income and $\color{blue}{CDF(x)}$ is proportion of incomers lesser than $\color{blue}{x}$.

So there is no useful $\color{blue}{PDF(x)}$ interpretation in Pareto Distribution for Pareto Principle application. It's obviously related to a slope (difference  of proportion of population below income $\color{blue}{x}$ on income difference), for each income $\color{blue}{x}$:

$$\color{blue}{\color{blue}{PDF(X) =\Delta CDF(x) /\Delta x }}$$

And it's explain why $\color{blue}{PDF(X_M)}$ is the bigger value. The proportion variation with income starts high, then slows  and after it fades slowly.

Comment: As for a reasonable interpretation of the pdf, the J-shaped positively skewed Pareto density is often used to graduate the upper tail of income distributions. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Applications) might have some details.

Comment: Yes, I know. I think that it's because there is a  smoothing decaying for low alpha values, due to exponential functions with negative exponent. However, in  this case,  my trouble was PDF interpretation in Pareto principle. CDF is presented as the  origin of Pareto Distribution in wikipedia article, but it not was stated in clear terms there.

Comment: I've undestood your point. I have to edit the answer. There is not true that there is no useful interpretation for PDF(x) function in Pareto Distribution. There is no useful interpretation for PDF(x) function in that case related to Pareto Principle,

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/24204/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you would find this helpful, but here is a possible explanation of the [genesis](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ti_OBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA2&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) of the Pareto distribution:

Suppose $N_x$ is the number of individuals in a community having income at least $x$.

Then, $$N_x\propto x^{-a}\quad,\,a>0$$

Consequently, the proportion of individuals having income at least $x$ in the community is also proportional to $x^{-a}$ for $a>0$.

Let $X$ be the random variable denoting income with distribution function $F$. Then based on the above observation, one can assume that $$1-F(x)\propto x^{-a}\quad,\,a>0$$

That is, $$1-F(x)=Ax^{-a}\quad,\text{ for some }A$$

Or, $$F(x)=1-Ax^{-a}$$

Let $k$ be the least income earned by an individual in the given community.

Then, $$P(X\geqslant k)=1-F(k)=1$$

So, $$A=k^a$$

Finally the distribution function looks like

$$F(x)=\left[1-\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)^a\right]\mathbf1_{x\geqslant k}$$

, from which the density of a Pareto distribution with shape $a$ and scale $k$ is derived as

$$f(x)=\frac{ak^a}{x^{a+1}}\mathbf1_{x\geqslant k}\quad,\,a>0,k>0$$

The above description is a version of the celebrated [Pareto law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle), and $a$ here is called the Pareto constant.

Comment: Perhaps not intentionally, but you fully clarified my doubt.  
In fact, the PDF(x) had no interpretation that I imagined, the population proportion is built-in associated to CDF(x), so there is no direct PDF(x) interpretation. It's something related to differential of proportion of population above income X, for each income X.